# device supports x86_64 arm64-v8 but apk only supports armeabi-v7a,x86 on device pixel XL api 34 stack overflow

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a Google Pixel device running API 34, which supports x86_64 and arm64-v8 architectures. However, I'm encountering an issue while trying to install an APK on my device.

The APK only supports armeabi-v7a and x86 architectures, which do not match my device's architecture. As a result, I getting this type of error in fig[image]

if you have the same type of error then, please check the answer. I found the solution after a long search. so share with the community.

Answer (score 0):

add the following code in you gradel

android {
...
defaultConfig {
...
ndk {
abiFilters 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a'
}
}
}[image]